# Is it good approach to Find Maximums from nested SQL query and then use that maximum value again in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it a good approach to Find Maximums from nested SQL query and then use that maximum value again in the same query.

For example:

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col2/Col3 AS Col4,  CASE Alot of statements END Col5
from Table A  inner join Table B on A.Id = B.Id
Inner Join Table C on B.Id = C.Id
Inner Join Table D on C.Id = D.Id
```

Now I need to find Maximum integer from `Col5` and then later use that Max Value to divide `Col4` value.
I also need to display `col1` and `col2` along with results.

Expected result:
**Col1, Col2, (Col4/MaxValue of Col5)**

Could anybody guide me what's the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are the only results you need, then no subquery/CTE is needed:

```
Select Col1, Col2, 
       ( (Col2 / Col3) /
        max(case Alot of statements end) over ()
       ) as  ratio
from Table A inner join
     Table B
     on A.Id = B.Id Inner Join
     Table C
     on B.Id = C.Id Inner Join
     Table D
     on C.Id = D.Id;
```

Tim's answer is definitely a good answer if you need `col5` more than once in the final result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col2/Col3 AS Col4,
           CASE Alot of statments END Col5
    FROM TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B
        ON A.Id = B.Id
    INNER JOIN TableC C
        ON B.Id = C.Id
    INNER JOIN TableD D
        ON C.Id = D.Id
)
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2,
       t.Col4 / MAX(t.Col5) OVER ()
FROM cte t
```